# bootstrap 4 drop down not coming right aligned

Tags: html, css

[image]I am facing lot of difficulty in aligning

1)Caret in the drop down to the end of the drop down on right hand side.

2 I am not able to align items to left when drop down is expanded.

Marker is added to explain the problem

Complete code is given here.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"/>
<style>
.multiselect.dropdown-toggle.btn {
    text-align: left;
    font-size:10px;
    height:30px;
    border-radius:0px;
    background-color:white;
    outline: none;
    border-color:black
    }


   .dropdown-menu{
       font-size:9px
    }
    .btn .caret {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    }

</style>
</head>

<div style="display:inline-block">
  <input type="text" style="background-color:grey;border:1px;height:25px;color:white;text-align:center;width:100px;margin-left:10px;font-size:10px" value="Select"/>
  <input type="text" style="background-color:grey;border:1px;height:25px;color:white;text-align:center;width:100px;font-size:10px" value="Select "/>
  <input type="text" style="background-color:grey;border:1px;height:25px;color:white;text-align:center;width:150px;font-size:10px" value="Select "/>
  <input type="text" style="background-color:grey;border:1px;height:25px;color:white;text-align:center;width:200px;font-size:10px" value="Select "/>
  <input type="text" style="background-color:grey;border:1px;height:25px;color:white;text-align:center;width:150px;font-size:10px" value="Select "/>
  <input type="text" style="background-color:grey;border:1px;height:25px;color:white;text-align:center;width:150px;font-size:10px" value="Select "/>
  <input type="text" style="background-color:grey;border:1px;height:25px;color:white;text-align:center;width:100px;font-size:10px" value="Select "/>
  <input type="text" style="background-color:grey;border:1px;height:25px;color:white;text-align:center;width:120px;font-size:10px" value="Select "/>  
<div>
<div style="display:inline-block">
<span style="margin-left:10px" />
<select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
<select id="example-getting-started1" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
<select id="example-getting-started2" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
<select id="example-getting-started3" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
<select id="example-getting-started4" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
<select id="example-getting-started5" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
<select id="example-getting-started6" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
<select id="example-getting-started7" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>



<div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function (){
    $('#example-getting-started').multiselect({
       buttonWidth: '100px',
       includeSelectAllOption: true
    });

    $('#example-getting-started1').multiselect({
       buttonWidth: '100px',
       includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
    $('#example-getting-started2').multiselect({
       buttonWidth: '150px',
       includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
    $('#example-getting-started3').multiselect({
       buttonWidth: '200px',
       includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
    $('#example-getting-started4').multiselect({
       buttonWidth: '150px',
       includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
    $('#example-getting-started5').multiselect({
       buttonWidth: '150px',
       includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
    $('#example-getting-started6').multiselect({
       buttonWidth: '100px',
       includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
    $('#example-getting-started7').multiselect({
       buttonWidth: '120px',
       includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
  }
  );
</script>
```

As you can see I tried to apply style .caret with float:right style but it is not working.

I tried to Align items to left when drop down area is expanded in li element but it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to edit the caret position you need to fix `.dropdown-toggle::after` css, with @Cuong Hoang or the following CSS, both of them will work. Just remember to correctly point to the wanted `.dropdown-toggle` if you don't want other caret to get re-positioned.

```
.btn.multiselect.dropdown-toggle::after {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 7px;
}
```

While, in order to fix the checkbox alignment in each of dropdown, you have to fix the padding of each label.

```
.multiselect-container > li > a > label {
  padding: 3px; 20px 3px 0;
}
```

Check working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hdoe9fbz/)

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go !

You cannot use text-align on this, because default implementation of bootstrap restrict it alot, the easy solution is customize like this. I dont know any other way that explain easier than this.

```css
.dropdown-toggle {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 12px;
    top: 13px;
}

.multiselect-container  > li {
    padding-top: 5px !important;
    padding-bottom: 5px !important;
    padding-left: 5px !important;
}

.multiselect-container  > li > a > label {
    padding: 0px !important;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
}

.multiselect-container  > li > a > label > input {
    margin: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"/>
<style>
.multiselect.dropdown-toggle.btn {
    text-align: left;
    font-size:10px;
    height:30px;
    border-radius:0px;
    background-color:white;
    outline: none;
    border-color:black
    }


   .dropdown-menu{
       font-size:9px
    }
    .btn .caret {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    }

</style>
</head>

<div style="display:inline-block">
  <input type="text" style="background-color:grey;border:1px;height:25px;color:white;text-align:center;width:100px;margin-left:10px;font-size:10px" value="Select"/>
  <input type="text" style="background-color:grey;border:1px;height:25px;color:white;text-align:center;width:100px;font-size:10px" value="Select "/>
  <input type="text" style="background-color:grey;border:1px;height:25px;color:white;text-align:center;width:150px;font-size:10px" value="Select "/>
  <input type="text" style="background-color:grey;border:1px;height:25px;color:white;text-align:center;width:200px;font-size:10px" value="Select "/>
  <input type="text" style="background-color:grey;border:1px;height:25px;color:white;text-align:center;width:150px;font-size:10px" value="Select "/>
  <input type="text" style="background-color:grey;border:1px;height:25px;color:white;text-align:center;width:150px;font-size:10px" value="Select "/>
  <input type="text" style="background-color:grey;border:1px;height:25px;color:white;text-align:center;width:100px;font-size:10px" value="Select "/>
  <input type="text" style="background-color:grey;border:1px;height:25px;color:white;text-align:center;width:120px;font-size:10px" value="Select "/>  
<div>
<div style="display:inline-block">
<span style="margin-left:10px" />
<select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
<select id="example-getting-started1" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
<select id="example-getting-started2" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
<select id="example-getting-started3" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
<select id="example-getting-started4" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
<select id="example-getting-started5" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
<select id="example-getting-started6" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
<select id="example-getting-started7" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>



<div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function (){
    $('#example-getting-started').multiselect({
       buttonWidth: '100px',
       includeSelectAllOption: true
    });

    $('#example-getting-started1').multiselect({
       buttonWidth: '100px',
       includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
    $('#example-getting-started2').multiselect({
       buttonWidth: '150px',
       includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
    $('#example-getting-started3').multiselect({
       buttonWidth: '200px',
       includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
    $('#example-getting-started4').multiselect({
       buttonWidth: '150px',
       includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
    $('#example-getting-started5').multiselect({
       buttonWidth: '150px',
       includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
    $('#example-getting-started6').multiselect({
       buttonWidth: '100px',
       includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
    $('#example-getting-started7').multiselect({
       buttonWidth: '120px',
       includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
  }
  );
</script>
```

Comment: Please add a little bit of an explaination of what you have done here. We are not here to do other people's homework but to help them getting through issues..

Comment: @Yuri I did explain, why do you down vote my answert, at least I help people alot, jesus

Comment: I have already explained that I tried to add float:right  Also there is one more thing that when drop down expanded items are not coming left aligned.

Comment: @Yuri if you keep downvoting time and efforts of other people then no one wants to help anymore, pls upvote it so that we have motivation to keep helping

Comment: Please read the question properly it has two aspect to it understand there are newbie who will be asking questions.

Comment: @CuongHoang your answer didn't have any explaination at first. Now you added it and I will remove the downvote.. Take it easy man

Comment: SO you want the item left-aligned ? @MihirkumarJoshi

Comment: Yes I am newbie I want item left align. Thanks for your help. I didnot devote may be someone else has done it.

Comment: @Yuri from where u say that i didnt not answer the question, dont u read the question first ? Mikhirkumar want to make things done as he said and i did, omg u cruel !!

Comment: @CuongHoang please stop being a victim here!! The OP asks to move the caret to right position and align the dropdown's element to the left, which is something you didn't do. Read post carefully